# How do Android's new Toolbar and the Contextual Action Bar work together?

Tags: android, android-actionbar, contextual-action-bar

I'm redesigning my current app roughly following Chris Bane's [excellent intro here](https://chris.banes.me/2014/10/17/appcompat-v21/). One thing struck me, though:

If I set the new v7-appcompat `Toolbar` as actionbar replacement via `setSupportActionBar()` and derive my theme from `Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar`, then the contextual action bar (CAB) will still pop up and push my contents, including the Toolbar, down:

[image]

Now, I could try to make the CAB overlay my Toolbar, but I figured the UI (basically the metrics and placement) of the back button and text of the CAB don't match the Toolbar either (as seen in the image), so I wonder if there is rather a "CAB" mode in the Toolbar implementation so that the Toolbar could take over this role as well?

Answer (score 31, accepted):

You need to set the following in your theme:

```
<item name="windowActionModeOverlay">true</item>
```

This will make the action mode overlay for content view, and therefore your Toolbar.

Comment: Many thanks for the pointer, Chris! As I thought, overlaying is the solution. However, as you can see on the screenshot above, there are several visual issues: (1) The back button that dismisses the CAB is placed more on the right than the one from the toolbar, (2) there is a light bar left of "Textauswahl", and (3) the CAB seems to be a few dp smaller in height than the Toolbar (for which I use `attr/actionBarSize`). Is this expected or are these visual glitches that will be fixed?

Comment: What is to be done if we set some height to the toolbar separate from wrap_content , then the CAB is not able to overlay the toolbar completely.how can we set the width of CAB then.